# cosine similarity between string and list of strings

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cosine-similarity

I have a string which I'm trying to compare to a list of strings. The objective is to rank the list of strings from most similar to least similar using cosine similarity.

```
original_string = 'abc'
string_list = ['abc', 'abcd', 'abec', 'ab', 'abcde', 'qwe']
```

That's my code so far:

```
sparse_matrix = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(string_list)
doc_term_matrix = sparse_matrix.todense()
df = pd.DataFrame(
                 doc_term_matrix,
                 columns=tfidf_vectorizer.get_feature_names(),
                 index=[df_list],
        )
        
cosine = pd.DataFrame(cosine_similarity(df))
```

However this does pairwise between elements in the dataframe and I'm not sure how to transform the single string into a vector and add it as an argument to the cosine_similarity function as Y?

Comment: So for ranking you want the cosine similarity between the strings?

Comment: yes, that's correct

Answer (score 2):

Hope I get you correct, so you need to vectorize it together with the list. One way is to append the string list to the test string. Once you have the matrix, its a matter of correlating the first row, to all other rows:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

string = 'aba'
string_list = ['abc', 'abcd', 'abec', 'ab', 'abcde', 'qwe']

tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer="char")

sparse_matrix = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform([string]+string_list)
cosine = cosine_similarity(sparse_matrix[0,:],sparse_matrix[1:,:])
```

Now we can put the results in a dataframe:

```
pd.DataFrame({'cosine':cosine[0],'strings':string_list}).sort_values('cosine',ascending=False)

cosine  strings
0   1.000000    abc
3   0.779625    ab
2   0.771964    abec
1   0.720181    abcd
4   0.619448    abcde
5   0.000000    qwe
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you need DataFrames for. But the following code calculates cosine_transform of your `string` (which I renamed to `tgt_string` below as `string` is a bit too generic of a name against each element of `string_list`

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

tgt_string = 'abc'
string_list = ['abc', 'abcd', 'abec', 'ab', 'abcde', 'qwe']

tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
sparse_matrix = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(string_list)
doc_term_matrix = sparse_matrix.toarray()

tgt_transform = tfidf_vectorizer.transform([tgt_string]).toarray()
tgt_cosine = cosine_similarity(doc_term_matrix,tgt_transform)
print(tgt_cosine)
```

this produces

```
[[1.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]]
```

which are `cosine_simulatity`-ies of tgt_string against each element of the list `string_list`. If you want it printed prettily in a dataframe, you can furthermore do

```
pd.DataFrame(index = string_list, data = tgt_cosine, columns = [tgt_string])
```

to generate

```
        abc
abc     1.0
abcd    0.0
abec    0.0
ab      0.0
abcde   0.0
qwe     0.0
```